# Should the "How to Ask" box on the "Ask question" form include some kind of "show the actual error message" recommendation?

Tags: discussion

It would be helpful if there was a recommendation along the lines of "if you are experiencing an error, please copy and paste the full error message into your question" (along with a link to a more detailed FAQ entry about how to do that; how to run `emacs --debug-init` or otherwise generate a stack trace; etc).

It's not uncommon for answerers to have to request the error or a stack trace from the asker before any headway can be made.

It would be nice if askers had a pointer about these things right at the very beginning.

Comment: 1. I don't think we should second-guess what the question might be about. Unless, say, the user used a tag that suggested an error. 2. There are so many ways in which we often need to ask for additional info that this one doesn't strike me as more important or generally applicable. IOW, what extra info might be appropriate depends on what the question is.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I'm not suggesting we second-guess anything. I'm simply saying that in cases where the user *intends to mention that there was an error*, that we try to encourage them to *tell us what it was*.

Comment: Yes, if we can tell that a user intends that then we should encourage that. Agreed.